# regularization of sum $n \ln(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, riemann-zeta, regularization

I was testing out a few summation using my previous descriped methodes when i found an error in my reasoning. I'm really hoping someone could help me out.

The function which i was evaluating was 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\ln(n)$ which turns out to be $-\zeta'(-1)$. This made me hope i could confirm my previous summation methode for divergent sums.

My divergent summtion methode (see previous questions) gives for every $d\geqslant2$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(dn)-f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{d-1} f(n)e^{ip\pi2n/d}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{d-1} -(d)^{2k} n\ln(d^kn)e^{2i\pi*pn/d}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \ln(n) \tag 1$$

Fill in $d=2$ cause that's the most easy, gives:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -(2)^{2k}k n\ln(2)(-1)^n-(2)^{2k} n\ln(n)(-1)^n$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -(4)^{k} n\ln(n)(-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  n\ln(n)/3(-1)^n \tag 2$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -(2)^{2k}k n\ln(2)(-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{4}{9}n\ln(2)(-1)^n= \frac{1}{9}\ln(2) \tag 3$$

equation (1)=(2)+(3)
$$(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n*n \ln(n)/3)+\ln(2)/9\approx 0.165421153 \tag 4$$

Now i work out $\lim_{m\to\infty}  \sum_{n=1}^{m} n \ln(n)$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m} n \ln(n)=m(m+1)\ln(m+1)/2-(m)(m+2)/4+\ln(m+1)/12+error \tag 5$$
It turns out the error is most likely $-1/6+~0.165421153$ so the value above.
The fact i get an expression with the value found above is cool. Actualy i'm close but

$\textbf{[Question]}$ why the $-1/6$. Did i failed isolating a constant part in my approximation? And if so were did i fail to get it out.

Ps: since i guessed the formula, it would be nice if someone could confirm the fomula if correct (or false).

Comment: Well orginaly i was intrested why there was another constant part -1/6. At first i beliefed (  incorrectly) that the above found estimation would be the constant part. Than i found out you can ofcours shift the general formula ( see the post of Claude Leibovici) shift the constant part. So now i need to reconsider what this constant part means and if there's a more beautiful formula were the constant part shines. And i've some ideas, because i can create a formula which includes the decreasing parts ( which goes to 0). But those are still ideas.

Comment: Ps: ofcours your right about the n and m.

Comment: Obviously what i did "wrong" was that i let my own found formula for the sum be "shifted" And the formula above should turn into the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), the asymptotic expansion of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(k)k^{-s}$ is
$$
-\zeta'(s)+\frac{n^{1-s}\log(n)}{1-s}-\frac{n^{1-s}}{(1-s)^2}+\frac{\log(n)}{2n^s}-\frac{s\log(n)}{12n^{1+s}}+\frac{n^{-1-s}}{12}+O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{3+s}}\right)\tag{1}
$$
Setting $s=-1$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)k=-\zeta'(-1)+\frac{n^2\log(n)}{2}-\frac{n^2}4+\frac{n\log(n)}2+\frac{\log(n)}{12}+\frac1{12}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\tag{2}
$$
According to $(1)$, the error term should be $O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}\right)$. However, if we compute two more terms at $s=-1$, we get that the error in $(2)$ is $\sim\frac1{720n^2}$.

In any case, the formula in equation $(5)$ from the question is
$$
\frac{n^2\log(n)}2-\frac{n^2}4+\frac{n\log(n)}2+\frac{\log(n)}{12}+\frac14+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\tag{3}
$$
However, the correct constant term is
$$
-\zeta'(-1)+\frac1{12}=0.248754477\tag{4}
$$
which is close to $\frac14$, but not exact.

Comment: When i asked this question i just had some represetation of the summation. Your answer is basicaly what i found later on, thanks for it btw! But what i didn't distinguish clearly enough before was the difference between the regulized value; the constant to make the series "fit", and the constant factor $n^0$ which is part of the series itself.

Comment: This is why I included formula $(1)$ for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log(k)k^{-s}$.  If you notice, the part that is constant with respect to $n$ is $-\zeta'(s)$. However, when $s=-1$, the $\frac{n^{-1-s}}{12}$ part also becomes constant with respect to $n$. For $s\lt-1$, that term grows with $n$, and needs to be accounted for the same as do the higher order terms. For $s\gt-1$, that term vanishes as $n\to\infty$. However, at $s=-1$, it neither gets bigger nor vanishes, it becomes an additional constant $\frac1{12}$.

Comment: Thanks for the additional context. I haven't used Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula before, so i'm going to give it a shot finding it myself, that's after all how i ended up with those questions. I've however before written a sum as integral, i ended up maybe with sums of sin's. I got a gutfeeling it's in there.

Comment: I apologize for not adding the link to Wikipedia. I usually include the link when citing the Sum Formula. I have added it now.

Comment: @Gerben: you are free to accept any answer you wish. However, I am curious why you switched after so long a time and after no change has been made to either this or the newly accepted answer. My curiosity does not mean you *need* to give a reason :-)

Comment: there was no reason, i was just reading back since i wanted a formula i found here. clicked on it by accedent on my phone. this answer is back on being awesome since it's the most precise

Comment: The $O\!\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n^{3+s}}\right)$ error term in $(1)$ is actually $\frac{s(s+1)(s+2)\log(n)-3s^2-6s-2}{720n^{3+s}}$, which for $s=-1$, turns into $\frac1{720n^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

***[update 2]*** : the answer is based on a wrong formula; the OP has corrected his formula (1) and thus all the reasoning down to eq (4) are historical now. Possibly I should delete that answer for simply cleaning up things...

---

***Possibly obsolete now:***

---

I begin with that in your post

> $d\geqslant2$:
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{d-1} (d^2)^{k} \ln(d^kn)e^{2i\pi*pn/d}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \ln(n)$$
>   Fill in $d=2$ cause that's the most easy, gives:

For $d=2$ the innermost loop resolves into one single pass, making the $e^{...}$ the factor $(-1)^n$. Shifting the $(2^2)^k$ out of the then inner loop (where it is a constant) and also separating $\ln(2^k n)$ into $(k \ln2 + \ln n)$ I get the more explicite version:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4^{k} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (\ln(n) + k\ln2) \overset{??}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \ln(n) \tag 1$$ 
The lhs can possibly -*with arguments from the concept of divergent summation of alternating series (here Cesaro-summation would suffice)*- be separated into
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4^{k} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \ln(n) + 
    \ln2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4^{k} k \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n  \tag 2
$$

But we have $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \ln(n) = \eta'(0) \approx  0.225791352645$, a constant. And also, $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n = - \eta(0)=- \frac 12$.
So we can furtherly reduce:
$$  \eta'(0) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4^{k} - \frac 12 \ln2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4^{k} k \tag 3$$
and after that, using the rational expression of the geometric series I arrive at  :
$$ {  0.225791352645 \over -3} - {\frac 12 \ln2 \cdot 4\over 9} \approx -0.229296491006 \tag 4$$

***[update]*** On the other hand, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \ln(n) = -\zeta'(-1) \approx 0.165421143700 $$ $\qquad \qquad \qquad$ *(the numerical value obtained by Pari/GP's `-zeta'(-1)`)*

so it seems, that the identity in (1) does not hold.

---

So possibly you (and not me...) made some algebraic error because you arrive at

> Fill in $d=2$ cause that's the most easy, gives:
>   $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n*n \ln(n)/3)+\ln(2)/9\approx 0.165421153$

where you have the cofactor $n$ in the first part and miss the $- 4\cdot \frac 12$ in the second part. *(I hope I've got things correct so far...)*

Comment: Maple confirms that, outputting $-\zeta  \left( 1,-1 \right) =0.1654211437$.

Comment: Note that $\;\eta'(0)=\frac 12\ln\frac {\pi}2\;$ but I think there is a problem with $(4)$ since $\;\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k} k =\frac x{(x-1)^2}$ (making $\frac 19\mapsto \frac 49\cdots$ still not fitting).

Comment: @Raymond: upps... I'l correct it

Comment: The moment i read your post I saw I made a notation error i'll edit is asap. I forgot to write a n down in the "extention". I feel really sorry you put so much time in a mistake of mine.

Comment: I missed a n $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{p=1}^{d-1} (d^2)^{k} >n< \ln(d^kn)e^{2i\pi*pn/d}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \ln(n)$ this one i missed to type down. Again my sincere apology you put so much efford in such a simple mistake. My estimation is not too deep, so i might be off a bit. Your last calculation was perfect btw :D

Comment: Now i look at it again i might have missed a minus sign aswell, to extend a given fuction i use $\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}f(dn)-f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}\sum_{p=1}^{d-1} f(n)e^{ippi2n/d}$  $\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\inf}\sum_{p=1}^{d-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\inf} -d^kf(d^kn)e^{ippi2n/d}$ If i remember correctly.

Comment: I've add the minus sign aswell. I always forget that little thing. How i got my extention is by starting to create a duplicate series and than isolating the constant part. And i know it's not working universal because i got troubles with series close to the harmonic series. They will miss actualy constants. But it works for (nearly all) other series.

Comment: @Gerben - perhaps you can insert the more explicte derivations of mine (with respect to your current modifications) into your post? It would make your claim much more readable and after any error/discreoancy in this is removed, one could look at the second step (the rational formula with the error). Perhaps you might consider to add equation-numbers too, with the /tag # option in the MathJax...

Comment: I've add the derivations, i hope it makes it clear what i'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how much this could help you; so, forgive me if I am off-topic. Considering $$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m} n\log(n)=\log (H(m))$$ where $$H(m)=\prod_{k=1}^m k^k$$ denotes the hyperfactorial function (defined for positive integers).

For large values of $m$, we can build asymptotics which, limited to second order, give $$S_m=m^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \log(m)-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2} m
   \log (m)+\left(\log (A)+\frac{1}{12} \log
   (m)\right)+\frac{1}{720
   m^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^3\right)$$ in which $A$ is  Glaisher's constant $(\approx 1.28243)$.

As you can see, if $m$ is large, you can just forget the last term and have a very good approximation.

To give an idea, $S_{10}\approx 102.082830552$ while the above formula leads to $\approx 102.082830572$.

**Edit**

If I use the formula, the maximum error is obtained for $m=1$ and the error is $\approx -1.437 \times 10^{-4}$. For $m=2$, the error becomes $\approx -1.114\times 10^{-5}$; for $m=3$, the error becomes  $\approx -2.327\times 10^{-6}$.

**Update**

After robjohn's comment, I extended the asymptotics to get 
$$S_m=m^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \log(m)-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2} m
   \log (m)+\left(\log (A)+\frac{1}{12} \log
   (m)\right)+\frac{1}{720
   m^2}-\frac{1}{5040
   m^4}+\frac{1}{10080 m^6}-\frac{1}{9504
   m^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^{10}}\right)$$

Comment: Your certainly on topic and my formula is nearly the same. It gives me something to google on atleast. But my constant part is different. My s10 gives a close value aswell and it might be a bit off because i just approximate them. And than i still wonder why the -1/6 shows up. Why isn't the constant equal to the regulated value. Which turns out to be Ln(A)-1/12

Comment: This is interesting ! Effectively, $\log(A)-\frac 1{12}\approx 0.1654211437$. I shall continue looking at this problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: I think that *nearly the same* has to be explored.

Comment: It's trivial that both formulas are "nearly the same" because the difference is: $\frac{6m^2+6m+1)ln(1+1/m)}{12}-m/2-3/12$ Well this goes to 0 really quick ofcours.

Comment: @Gerben: note that the $-3/12 = -1/4$ is accidentally(?) equal to $ \int_0^1 t \ln t dt $ which is a term which usually occurs in the Ramanujan-summation in divergent series like this as an additional leading term. And $-1/6 = -1/4 + 1/12$ ... Perhaps this has some significance to look at the MacLaurin-formula.

Comment: Intresting!  I'm not familair with the  MacLaurin-formula nor Ramanujan-summation yet what i'm doing turns out to be atleast related ( and awesome since it's works also for convergent sums). I hope by playing with these functions i can figure out ramanujan summation and the  MacLaurin-formula. Lately i'm under the impression what i do is not ramanujan summation, but the ramanujan sum of functions. Quite certain about it actualy. Maybe i can email you about this subject because it's not clear for me at all.

Comment: I've found this. Turns out it's 1/12 n^0 which isn't constant. Okey this is vague formulate but i'll make a post  and reasoning. This n^0 is the reason why i was sometimes off, I just had the feeling i got things about this subject, and it's so simple.

Comment: I see that $\log(A)=-\zeta'(-1)+\frac1{12}$ (which how the constant term is given in my answer). However, after  the $\frac1{720m^2}$ term, the next term is $-\frac1{5040m^4}$ (which is very close to the values you get for $m=2$ and $m=3$), so you could improve the error term to $O\!\left(\frac1{m^4}\right)$

Comment: @robjohn. Very nice remark. I update my answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: that's as far as the "pretty" terms go. The next two terms are $+\frac{691}{3603600\,m^{10}}-\frac1{1872\,m^{12}}$. The $691$ in the numerator is not as aesthetic.

Answer (score 1):

@Claude Leibovici I just found your solution, with a little bit different methode, but in the end it's the same and explains the difference in constant part to be found for a general solution.

When h goes to 0.
$$\sum_{n=1}^m n^{s+h}= \sum_{n=1}^m (n^s ( 1+h\ln(n))$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^m n^{s+h}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{s,i} m^{s+1+h-i} $$
At s=1
$$\sum_{n=1}^m n^{1}= m^2/2+m/2+m^0/12+...-1/12$$

The whole point i missed at first was the $m^0$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^m n^{1+h}= m^{2+h}/(2+h)+m^{1+h}/2+m^h*(h+1)/(12)+...+\zeta(-1-h)$$ 
$$\sum_{n=1}^m n\ln(n)= m^2/2\ln(m)-m^2/4 ＋m/2\ln(m)+1/12ln(n) +(m^0)/12+ ... -\zeta' (-1)$$ 
This $\zeta'(-1)$ is like said before $1/12-ln(A)$.

so we get  $-1/12+ln(A)$ as the new constant ( and the answer of the regularization of the summation) and the $m^0/12$ is part of the function itself. This is were i got confused in the start. Thanks for all the help, this example helped me a lot.