# Is there any formula to calculate $ \sum_{n=2}^{x} \frac{n}{\ln(n)} $?

Tags: summation, logarithms

Is there any formula to calculate $ \sum_{n=2}^{x} \frac{n}{\ln(n)} $?
As we know, there are a formula to calculate $ \sum_{n=1}^{x} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^s} $
Using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), that is mentioned on [this question ( math.stackexchange)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404512/regularization-of-sum-n-lnn)
Now, I want to know is there any formula for this summation?

Comment: Why are you interested in this summation?

Comment: For personal research about the summation and 
I wonder if there is? Because No matter what I searched for, I could not find anything

Comment: Technically, you want an estimate, not a closed exact formula, right?

Comment: i have found the estimated formula for this, but i want to know is there any exact formula or better estimated form?

Comment: The obvious problem with Euler-Maclaurin sum method here is that, I think, $\int \frac{x}{\ln x}\,dx$ has no closed formula in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: What is your estimate for this? We can't tell if we've found a better estimate if we don't know your estimate. (Put in the question, not the comments.)

Comment: i will write it some minutes later here

Comment: An asymptotic expansion for large $x$ is $$
\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{n}{{\log n}}}  \sim \frac{{x^2 }}{{2\log x}}\left( {1 + \frac{{1!}}{{2\log x}} + \frac{{2!}}{{(2\log x)^2 }} + \frac{{3!}}{{(2\log x)^3 }} +  \ldots } \right).
$$

Comment: yes i had found same

Comment: You can truncate it at the least term (after $\left\lfloor {2\log x} \right\rfloor$ terms) and add further contributions coming from Euler-Maclaurin, such as $\frac{x}{2\log x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approximation with error term may be derived as follows. It is not difficult to show via the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) that
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{k}{{\log k}}}  = \int_2^n {\frac{t}{{\log t}}\mathrm{d}t}  + \frac{n}{{2\log n}} + K + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right),
$$
where
$$
K = \frac{{11}}{{12\log 2}} + \frac{1}{{12\log ^2 2}} + \int_2^{ + \infty } {\left( {\left\{ t \right\}^2  - \left\{ t \right\} + \frac{1}{6}} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{{2t\log ^2 t}} - \frac{1}{{t\log ^3 t}}} \right)\!\mathrm{d}t} .
$$
In terms of the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}$, we can write
$$
\int_2^n {\frac{t}{{\log t}}\mathrm{d}t}  = \operatorname{Ei}(2\log n) - \operatorname{Ei}(2\log 2).
$$
Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{k}{{\log k}}}  = \operatorname{Ei}(2\log n) + \frac{n}{{2\log n}} + C + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right),
$$
with
$$
C = K - \operatorname{Ei}(2\log 2) =  - 1.47166722580 \ldots \,.
$$
A further simplification is possible by using Theorem $8.1$ of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.08504) paper which implies
$$
\operatorname{Ei}(2\log n) = \frac{{n^2 }}{{2\log n}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{\left\lfloor {2\log n} \right\rfloor } {\frac{{m!}}{{(2\log n)^m }}}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {\log n} }}} \right).
$$
Accordingly,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{k}{{\log k}}}  = \frac{{n^2 }}{{2\log n}}\left( {\frac{1}{n} + \sum\limits_{m = 0}^{\left\lfloor {2\log n} \right\rfloor } {\frac{{m!}}{{(2\log n)^m }}} } \right) + C + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {\log n} }}} \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Very nice, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So it can be concluded that there are not any exact formulae, but the best estimate for this summation is:

$$\sum_{n<x} \frac{n}{\ln{(n)}} \sim \frac{x^2}{2\ln{x}} \left(1+ \frac{1!}{2\ln{x}} +  \frac{2!}{(2\ln{x})^2}  +  \frac{3!}{(2\ln{x})^3} + \ldots \right) $$

Comment: Try $$
\frac{{x^2 }}{{2\log x}}\left( {\frac{1}{x} + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor {2\log x} \right\rfloor } {\frac{{k!}}{{(2\log x)^k }}} } \right).
$$

Comment: Thats great. Thanks alot

Comment: Not exact but so good !

Comment: Is there a derivation that can be shared?

Comment: @Aruralreader I added one.